# Delete Alarm :Android

Tags: android

Here's my addAlarm() Method :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ALReciver.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 10 , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT|  Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

         AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent );
```

This code work fine but i want delete this alaram usning following code :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, ALReciver.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,10, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.cancel(sender);
```

this code is not working.. i am not understand What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Replce:

```
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,10, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

to

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 10 , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT|  Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my sample of start,cancel

I am used same intent. but your mistake is this. pending intent give to common button click time perform action as start and cancel use with that intent then success.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_alarm);


        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(Alaram.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

        findViewById(R.id.btn_startAlarm).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                start();
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.btn_stopAlarm).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cancel();
            }
        });


    }

    public void start() {
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int interval = 8000;

        manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void cancel() {
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

It's working fine for me are u try this one.

Comment: @Rohit are u try this one?

Comment: Thanks @bhuvaneshwaran Vellingiri. I am not using this code because  My issue is resolved using  follwoing code  :                                                                       PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 10 , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT|  Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

Answer (score 0):

Change the Flag from `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` to `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`.

Comment: @RohitRananaware Try to use the exact same Intent in both start and cancel.

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel alarm. For that you need to create same intent:

```
alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
```